# Room Peristence Library and enigmatic error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I try to use Room in Android Studio 3.0 with kotlin. I have successfully created 3 entities that work well (database is created, i can insert rows and so on). Now, i want to add some functionnalities but i have this enigmatic error:

```
Warning:warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

Do you know how can I see "log for more details". Is there another way to point excatly where the error is ?

For the moment, I can find where the error is only by commenting one-by-one the portion of new codes i've added, until the compilation success.

By setting --stacktrace --debug for compiler option, the message is even more enigmatic:

```
Error:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
```

**[Edit]**
It's not a duplicate : the linked question in Emmanuel S comment is a runtime exception. In my case, it's a compile time problem. And, I can correct the bug but the question I ask is about the lack of information about where is excactly the problem.

**[Edit 2]**
I give some precision to my question by using an example.
Imagine this code:

```
@Dao
PersonDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM categoryes")
   fun getAll() : List<Categ>
   ...
}
```

A compile error is fired but I understand why : it's because i've made a type in categor**y**es. But the error message give no idea where the problem is. After correcting the typo, all is good.

So, is there a way to know where the problem is exactly ? I think it's nothing to do with annotationProcessor or kapt in build.gradle

**[Edit 3]** Problem has been solved with Kotlin plugin update (from 1.1.51 to version new version 1.1.60)

Now i've a clear error message:

```
Error:(9, 1) error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: categs)
```

So, was it really a duplicate ???

[image: clear message with new version of Kotlin plugin]

Comment: there are really a few hundred answers about that topic.

Comment: @Emmanuel S : sorry but it's not a duplicate : the problem in the question you've linked is a runtime exception. In my case, it's a compile time problem. And, I can correct the bug but the problem is the lack of information

Comment: I didnt mean that its exactly the same issue, but the solution is always the same. add the proper depdencies, invalidate cache and restart, add kotlin kapt instead of annotationProcessors, ...

Comment: @Owen Pauling, MikeT, Nilesh Rathod, KeLiuyue, I'm very sorry but, re-read my post attentively, especially my second edit : my problem is not Exception during runtime but a lack of information during compilation. So why mark my question as a duplicate ?

Comment: post your dao, model and gradle. ill try to help.

Comment: Are there any error messages above the "Error while annotation processing" exception? Also, what Kotlin Gradle plugin version do you use?